# CLIENT_ERROR: authentication required for primary source and source version master

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

my github token expired and i generated a new one but i'm still facing this error for some reason. i mad sure there's no spaces or anything in the value but still no luck. what could be other causing issue for this error?
i'm using terraform for my infrastructure.

Comment: please provide some example code

Comment: The solution for this was to update the token from the source config in the codebuild. this issue happend in one region only and i'm not sure why.

Comment: @DalalAlghomlas would be very helpful if you explained how you did that and made it an answer. Running into this issue right now and I have no idea where you go to update the token from the source config.